# Authorization has been denied for this request. Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, authorization, owin

New to Owin authorization and currently exploring.

I can now successfully get the token from the token host
[image]

I now try to access a controller with the [Authorize] attribute but seem to be getting a Authorization has been denied for this request issue.
[image]

[image]

I used the returned token as a bearer token but doesnt seem to work in post man. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shoot it was just a matter of order in the Startup.cs

I created called ConfigureAuth after WebApiConfig.Register(config); @.@